# Proving union of functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Does this proof look right?

Suppose f: A → C and g: B → C.Prove that if A and B are disjoint, then f ∪ g: A∪B→C.

Suppose x ∈ A.  That means f(x)=c.  Therefore, x ∉ B since A∪B=∅.
Suppose x ∈ B.  That means g(x)=c.  Therefore, x ∉ A since A∪B=∅.

Therefore, f ∪ g: A∪B→C.

Thanks!

Comment: No, not quite. Start with the definition of a function.

Comment: Presumably, you are supposed to show that for each pair of functions $f:A\to C$ and $g:B\to C$ there is a unique function $h:A\sqcup B\to C$ such that $h|_A=f$ and $h|_B=g$. So you should first try to define this $h$. You already did this, to some extent.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ and $B$ be disjoint sets and let $f\colon A\to C$ and $g\colon B\to C$ be functions.

By the definition of a function, $f\subseteq {?}$ and $g\subseteq {?}$.

Thus $f\cup g\subseteq{?}$.

Let $x\in A\cup B$. Then by definition of union ….

Let $(x,y) \in f\cup g$ and $(x,z)\in f\cup g$. Then ….